# Is this a correct way of pagination in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

On clicking "more" i call `loadNextPage` method that call `loadComments` method which load data based next id `nextCommentId` and push the data to  `allComments` array and this array is rendered in html

```
$scope.loadNextPage = function()
{
    loadComments($scope.nextCommentId);
}

function loadComments(page){
    $scope.allComments.push(d.data);
    ..
    ..
    $scope.nextCommentId = nextId;
}
```

Here is my html

```
<div ng-repeat="comment in allComments">
 ...
</div>
```

My question is, is this the correct way of doing pagination in angularjs as i am keeping all data in array so if data will grow it will consume memory.

Comment: Well it depends ... do you want to show all the data at once?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div data-pagination="" data-num-pages="numPages()" 
  data-current-page="currentPage" data-max-size="maxSize"  
  data-boundary-links="true"></div>

todos.controller("TodoController", function($scope) {
   $scope.filteredTodos = []
  ,$scope.currentPage = 1
  ,$scope.numPerPage = 10
  ,$scope.maxSize = 5;

  $scope.makeTodos = function() {
    $scope.todos = [];
    for (i=1;i<=1000;i++) {
      $scope.todos.push({ text:"todo "+i, done:false});
    }
  };
  $scope.makeTodos(); 

  $scope.numPages = function () {
    return Math.ceil($scope.todos.length / $scope.numPerPage);
  };

  $scope.$watch("currentPage + numPerPage", function() {
    var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage)
    , end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;

    $scope.filteredTodos = $scope.todos.slice(begin, end);
  });
});
```

Comment: `$scope.filteredTodos = $scope.todos.slice(begin, end);` is no different then  mine. at the end it is also keep pushing the data in an array